# Declare a function type with an arbitrary return type in golang

Tags: go

I'm new to go and have come across the following issue that I haven't been able to find covered in the tutorial or google searches, though I'm sure it must be a basic aspect of the language I have missed. I have code like the following:

```
type Task func()

var f Task = func() { fmt.Println("foo") }

type TaskWithValue func() interface{}

var g TaskWithValue = func() { return "foo" }

var h TaskWithValue = func() { return 123 }
```

In `f` above, there is no compiler error, but for `g` and `h` there are errors like the following:

```
Cannot use func() { return "foo" } (type func ()) as type TaskWithValue in assignment
```

Essentially, I'm trying to define a `Task` type that can have an arbitrary return type. In other languages, I would simply give `Task` a type parameter, like `Task<Integer>` or `Task<String>`, but since go does not have generics/templates, I understood the workaround is to use return type `interface{}` and then cast the results. What am I missing to get this example working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the return type in the anonymous function expressions:

```
var g TaskWithValue = func() interface{} { return "foo" }

var h TaskWithValue = func() interface{} { return 123 }
```